# Swift - bridging header compiler error

Tags: ios, swift, header-files, bridging-header

I added to my project bridging-header file so I can use opencv in swift.
I decided that I don't need opencv so I deleted the bridging header file , after I did it I couldn't run my project because of this error:

:0: error: error opening input file '/Users/user1/Desktop/project_name/project_name/project_name-Bridging-Header.h' (No such file or directory)

this error appeared in the **Compile Swift source files > Precompile bridging header** section.
I tried cleaning my derived data and I tried deleting the path in the **Swift Compiler - General > Objective c bridging header**.

Answer (score 4):

> You have to delete bridging header path from the **Buide setting**>**Swift Compiler - General** > **Objective c bridging header**
>
> > Please search your header file name in your project and if you find anything. then delete

Answer (score 0):

Just go to product and clink "Clean Build  Folder" option. That will fix the problem.