# Swift - Tries to open a bridging header that I have since deleted

Tags: swift

I'm playing around making a Swift CLI tool but I've run into a bit of a problem with bridging headers. I was going to use some c++ scripts, so I made a c++ file in the project in Xcode and agreed to Xcode making a bridging header for me. I realised a few minutes later that I could do the necessary coding in Swift, so I deleted the bridging header and c++ file.

But now, whenever I try to compile the project, I get an error saying 
    error opening input file '/path/to/project/ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h' (No         such file or directory)

Does anyone have any idea how to tell Xcode to stop looking for the header? I've tried the obvious tricks like saving and restarting.

Cheers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50080796/1187415

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode MyProjectName-Bridging-Header.h does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26096402/xcode-myprojectname-bridging-header-h-does-not-exist)

Comment: Thanks Martin, that link (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50080796/1187415) contained the answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift - bridging header compiler error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50080712/swift-bridging-header-compiler-error)