# Compile Swift source files failed

Tags: ios, objective-c, build, apple-m1

I am currently trying to run a 0.61 version React Native project to iPhone11 simulator through Xcode 13.4.1 .
But Build failed, when Compile Swift source files, Precompile Bridging Header.
Please have a look at error log as below.

```
PrecompileSwiftBridgingHeader normal arm64...
...App-Bridging-Header.pch
Debug-iphonesimulator/Charts/Charts.modulemap' not found
Charts/Charts.modulemap' not found
RNCharts.modulemap' not found
SwiftyJSON.modulemap' not found
```

According to the suggestion of https://stackoverflow.com/a/50080796/7284349.
I tried delete bridging header path from the Build setting > Swift Compiler - General > Objective c bridging header. But no work.

[image]

while here's the interesting thing, execute `react-native run-ios` in the terminal,  app can launch successfully on simulator,  shown as a blank screen. At least build success, no errors.  Such a strange thing!

Comment: Open Xcode using Rosetta,  then build successfully. But, but, but Simulator stuck after launched, app cannot launch on simulator.

Comment: restart simulator can work.